# Рандомный результат получения MAC адреса клиента

Tags: sql, sql-server

БД Ms SQL 11

Есть хранимка следующего содержания:

```
CREATE procedure dbo.proc_GetMAC
as
 Select net_address
 from master..sysprocesses
 where hostname = host_name()
 group by net_address
GO
```

Имеется две проблемы:

1. При выполнении процедуры через программы для работы с БД
   (Managment St и dbForage) процедура стабильно возвращает 2 мак
   адреса. Они не меняются, но при этом ничего общего с реальным мак
   адресом моей машины не имеют.
2. При вызове процедуры из кода
   программы (.Net) она возвращает 3 мак адреса и они рандомно
   изменяются и так же ни один из них не соответствует реальному мак
   адресу машины с которой идёт вызов процедуры.

Как сделать так, чтобы и при вызове через программы для работы с БД и при вызове из кода хранимка возвращала 1 мак соответствующий мак адресу вызывающей машины?

Comment: В англоязычном сегменте сети есть описания похожих проблем с net_address. Всё сводится к тому, что net_address не является надёжным источником мак-адреса подключенного пользователя, в частности, если, например, пользователь находится за маршрутизатором. Рекомендуют полагаться на Hostname и IP: `select sp.hostname, c.client_net_address, c.client_tcp_port from sys.sysprocesses sp join sys.dm_exec_connections c on c.session_id = sp.spid where sp.spid = @@spid`.